# Why do we need \ldots?

Tags: spacing, tex-core

While trying to understand Chapter 12 of Knuth's TeXbook about *Glueing*, I run into troubles in understanding why `\ldots` ends up in looking better than `...`. It seems to me that the usual period `.` has an extra-stretching option and, moreover, it is set to allow more space after it. I guess, but I am not sure, that this is part of the `\nofrenchspacing` command, where it is specified that the space after a dot should be `3@m` instead of `@m`. So, my questions are

1. First of all, am I right with the above guess that if I want to understand where TeX (or LaTeX) is told what to do with a period in non-frenchspaced text, this is in the `\nonfrenchspacing` command? Is it this after-space, which is called `spacefactor`?
2. More important: how does it come that if I put three dots in a row, they are *too close* apart? According to the above, there should be `3@m` after every period, so the three dots should be fine: but they aren't. Knuth says that TeX has a rule for determining the end of a sentence, but he does not tell us how (I am looking at page **73** of his TeXbook). In particular, I guess that there are two `spacefactor` commands, so to speak, one for end-of-sentence and one for middle-of-sentence. Is it possible to have some detail?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The spacefactor (`\sfcode`) does not add any space after the `.` it just increases the space that a space token after a `.` produces so in

```
This is the end. A new sentence
```

the end of sentence space will be a bit bigger and allowed to stretch more if the sfcode of `.` is not 1000.

If you go `...` there are no space tokens between the dots so the space factor code of `.` is not used.

The texbook says that if the current value of the space factor is *f* then:

> Take the normal space glue for the current font, and add the
>   extra space if *f* >= 2000  (Each font specifies a normal space, normal
>   stretch, normal shrink, and extra space; for example, these quantities are
>   3.33333pt, 1.66666pt, 1.11111pt, and 1.11111pt, respectively, in
>   `cmr10`. […])
>
> Then the stretch component is multiplied by *f*/1000, while the shrink
>   component is multiplied by 1000/*f*.

Here the relevant value of *f* is 3000 or 1000 for `\nonfrenchspacing` or `\frenchspacing` respectively.

Comment: Thank you, very clear indeed. Since you seem to have the TeXBook at hand, can you add a precise reference to your quotation and, may be, tell me where is the command `\sfcode` discussed? I see it has a syntax of the form `\sfcode')=0pt` but I'd like to study it in somewhat deeper detail.

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo chapter 12 (esp page 76)

Answer (score 8):

The key typographic difference between `...` and `\ldots` is *not* anything to do with the width of a subsequent space.  `\ldots` puts more spacing *in between* the dots.  Observe:

```
x...x\par
x\dots x\par
\bye
```

renders as

[image: rendering of above example, showing that the second case has more space between the dots]

(note: in plain TeX `\ldots` is math-only, you have to use `\dots` in text mode.)